# Why would plugging in my iPod Mini via FireWire hard crash my Mac running High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, ipod, kernel-panic, firewire

I have a MacPro3,1 that I've recently upgraded to High Sierra using the patch. I also still use an older 1st gen 64GB iPod Mini (yes, upgraded) that I've always connected to the machine via the FireWire 400 cable. Up until I did the High Sierra upgrade, the Mac and iPod had no issues.

If I plug the iPod into the Mac with the FireWire cable the screen immediately dies and the Mac reboots. If I leave the iPod plugged in, the computer will go into a continuous reboot loop (several seconds in between). I did notice in one of the generated Apple problem reports that it is a FireWire related kernel panic.

Any ideas why this would be happening? Is FireWire no longer supported on High Sierra perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried a USB cable instead of a FireWire 400 cable for your iPod? Do you have any other FireWire 400 devices you could plug in to troubleshoot if your Mac Pro has issues with its FireWire port?

Comment: @drivec I am able to sync it with the USB cable, but the nice thing about the FireWire cable is that it is a bit faster at everything (charging, syncing) than USB and also doesn't use one of my USB ports in the process.

Comment: I'm certain that FireWire 400 is still supported in High Sierra. Do other FireWire 400 devices cause kernel panics?

Comment: @drivec I don't have any FireWire devices to test with it other than iPod Minis :-/   (yes, they're for parts!)